# Understanding how to train my tensorflow CNN, line-by-line

Tags: python, tensorflow

Could someone help me understand what each line in the code below is doing?
I am new to tensorflow and very confused.

```
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    avg_cost = 0
    total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)

    for i in range(total_batch):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        c, _ = m1.train(batch_xs, batch_ys)
        avg_cost += c / total_batch

    print('Epoch:', '%04d' % (epoch + 1), 'cost =', 
'{:.9f}'.format(avg_cost))
```

I have defined the number of epochs. The code inside the for-loop trains the model by the number of iterations specified by training_epochs.

1. I don't understand what `batch_xs` and `batch_ys` are and why the result of `mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)` returns two values that are each defined as `batch_xs`and`batch_ys`.
2. `c, _ = m1.train(batch_xs, batch_ys)`. `c` is the cost, but what is the underscore?
3. Why is the cost modified by `c / total_batch` instead of `c` for each iteration?

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using hunkim's tutorial.

1. `mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)` basically returns the next batch to train. This probably would be MNIST CNN/DNN, which means you need the input and the label to feed into the network, namely the image of the handwritten digit (input) and what the correct prediction (label) should be. These respectively are `batch_xs` and `batch_ys`.
2. `m1.train` returns two objects, and the first is the cost of the step. `_` is a variable name conventionally used for something that you won't use.
3. `avg_cost` is printed only after an entire epoch is run. This suggests that `avg_cost` is the average cost of the epoch. Now, `c` is the average cost of one **step**. The total number of steps per epoch is **`total_batch`**. Then to compute the average cost of one **epoch**, you should add all the `c`s returned every step and divide that by `total_batch`. This is what's essentially being done; `avg_cost += c / total_batch`.

Answer (score 1):

1. For your 1st Q, you should probably include a bit more code. Without seeing the rest of the code, I can guess that `batch_xs, batch_ys` are `data, labels`.
2. `_` usually means an unwanted variable, meaning the function returns 2 objects, but you only want the first, so you denote the desired one in a meaningful name (`c`) and the other in a less so (`_`).
3. `c / total_batch` is exactly what you want. It is the proportional cost.